# Hide closest button of each class element

Tags: jquery

I want to find the closest button of the parent for each ".ImHere" class element.

```
$('.ImHere').each(function() {
    $(".ImHere" ).parent().nextAll('.add').first().css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nf50k7og/42/

But it doesn't work

Comment: $(".ImHere" ).parent().nextAll('.add').css( "background-color", "red" );

Comment: Hi, thx for your help, nextAll() make all following button as red whitout stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `.Imhere` again in the callback of `.each`

```js
$('.ImHere').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.add').first().css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="unique1">
  <div class="ImHere"></div>
</div>
<button class="zoom" type="button">Zoom</button>
<button class="add" type="button">Add</button>

<div id="unique2">
  <div class=""></div>
</div>
<button class="zoom" type="button">Zoom</button>
<button class="add" type="button">Add</button>

<div id="unique3">
  <div class="ImHere"></div>
</div>
<button class="zoom" type="button">Zoom</button>
<button class="add" type="button">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $("document").ready(function() {
      $('.ImHere').each(function() {
        $(".ImHere" ).parent().next("[type='button']").css( "background-color", "red" );
// OR if you want specific class
// $(".ImHere" ).parent().next(".add").css( "background-color", "red" );
      });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nf50k7og/54/

Answer (score 1):

you can also try like this

```
 $("document").ready(function() { $('.ImHere').parent().next('button').next('button.add').css('background-color','red') });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you wrap the unit in a container element. You can use `.closest()` to traverse upto common ancestor then use `.find()` to target it.

And use current element context i.e. `this`

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('.ImHere').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.add').css("background-color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="unique1">
    <div class="ImHere">ImHere</div>
  </div>
  <button class="zoom" type="button">Zoom</button>
  <button class="add" type="button">Add</button>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="unique1">
    <div class="ImHere">ImHere</div>
  </div>
  <button class="zoom" type="button">Zoom</button>
  <button class="add" type="button">Add</button>
</div>
```